# Trying to integrate Waterline, Informatica Metadata Manager, IBM InfoSphere Server and Cloudera Navigator

Tags: hadoop, metadata, cloudera, informatica, ibm-infosphere

I have metadata into several different repositories. They are

1. Waterline Data Inventory
2. Informatica Metadata Manager
3. IBM InfoSphere Server
4. Cloudera Navigator

Each of the above metadata management tools support different sources.

Is it possible to combine the metadata from any two or more of the above tools into a single repository for easy viewing and governance.

I appreciate all you guys for your assistance.

Comment: Yes you can do it through informatica to have all the metadata tables in a single repository. If you need more clarification, will explain you deeply

Comment: I would highly appreciate that. Do you mean through Powercenter?

Comment: Yes through power center

Comment: You need any guidance to do that?